# By including jQuery and jQuery UI, Am I loading jQuery twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been playing around with PHP and JavaScript and jQuery and installed a couple of jQuery plugins. Now in my header I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Is this loading two different things? Or can I get rid of one?

Comment: so ur question is `does jquery.min contain everything in jquery-ui.min`..right

Comment: Just a note: It's best practice to put your script tags before the close of your body tag. This way the parser has the document and its contained elements and can begin render before making new http requests to get and parse your scripts, which will make your page load and appear to the user quicker. - This is covered in depth in this lecture from the recent MS Build conference: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-132

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you are not loading twice. They are 2 different libraries for different purpose.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js is the jQuery library mainly for document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions. Check their [website](http://jquery.com/) documentation for information.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js is the jQuery UI library that contains the widgets like tabs/accordian/dialog and functions like animate/draggable/sortable and more. Check out [jQuery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/) for more information.

Comment: +1, and I would add: the second line is only required if you're actually using jQuery UI.

Comment: Not sure jqueryui 1.8 is compatible with jquery 1.5

Comment: @roasted jQuery UI v1.8.24 is compatible with jQuery 1.3.2+

Comment: I'd also add that jQuery UI depends on jQuery.